# MongoDB .push is returning null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is the GitHub repo I am currently working on: https://github.com/Stick-z/first-media-app

I am trying to make a website, and currently developing my backend.  I am setting up a jokes array in my category section, by using joke.push;  However, whenever I try to make a POST request to add a new joke, it returns `null` (in the console) and my request never finishes(using Insomnia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your code in github and I think following section has some issues. Please add it to your answer if thats the case.

```js
router.post("/:id/joke/new", (req, res) => {
  const newJoke = new Joke({
    user: req.body.user,
    text: req.body.text,
  });
  console.log(newJoke);
  console.log(Category.findById(req.params.id));
});
```

Clearly there is no adding-to-db logic so with my mongoose-fu I would change some things a bit.
Also I don't see any `res.send` or `res.json` in this method. You can return created updated object as json or any success/fail notification.

```js
router.post("/:id/joke/new", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { user, text } = req.body
  Category.findById(id)
    .then(doc => {
      if(doc) {
        doc.user = user;
        doc.text = text;
        doc.save().then(doc => res.json(doc))
        return;
      }

      const newJoke = new Joke({
        user,
        text,
      });

      newJoke.save().then(doc => res.json(doc))
    })
});
```

I don't know your business domain and could confuse models but I guess some things must be checked and then created.

Comment: oops, i forgot i deleted some code to isolate the problem.  But after replacing with that code, it didnt seem to work.  But then, I saw another stack overflow post, and ditched the Joke schema completely and used Gategory.findByIdAndUpdate and I was able to fix it :). Regardless, thank you for your answer :)).